# Inserting std::shared_ptr with lambda into a vector

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, shared-ptr, stdvector

I have a vector defined as:

```
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Orders> > vOrders;
```

When adding to `vOrders` I want to add like:

```
vOrders.push_back(<std::shared_ptr<Orders> >([]() {
    TimerForProcessingOrders _timerForProcessingOrders;
    _timerForProcessingOrders.detach();
}));
```

but the compiler is giving me an error:

```
Expected expression: Expected '(' for function-style cast or type construction
```

It looks weird the `<` and `>` around `std::shared_ptr`but removing it gives an error:

```
No matching conversion for functional-style cast from '<lambda >' to 'std::shared_ptr<Orders>'
```

What mistake am I making?

Comment: What do you expect to accomplish with the lambda?

Comment: What is Order? Please add its definition

Comment: Use `std::make_shared`. It also removes the issue of those extra angle brackets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What this code does (in an ill formed way) is take the object constructed by the lambda, and store the lambda itself into the vector -- not an object of type `shared_ptr<Order>` which is what the vector requires.

> but the compiler is giving me an error:

This is because the extra `< >` are completely invalid syntax, so the best the compiler can give you is "invalid expression".

> It looks weird the < and > around std::shared_ptrbut removing it gives an error:
>   `No matching conversion for functional-style cast from '<lambda >' to 'std::shared_ptr<Orders>'`

Basically what you have here is `shared_ptr<Orders>(/* .. Lambda .. */)` -- and the compiler is saying that it has no idea how to turn the lambda into an `Orders*` to go into the `shared_ptr`.

What are you actually trying to accomplish here?

If you just want to transfer a pointer into the `shared_ptr` you can do something like

```
TimerForProcessingOrders _timerForProcessingOrders;
std::shared_ptr<Orders> ptr(_timerForProcessingOrders.detach());
vOrders.emplace_back(std::move(ptr));
```

no lambda is required.

Comment: Well I read: http://www.baptiste-wicht.com/2012/03/cpp11-concurrency-part1-start-threads/ and liked the aspect of creating a thread with a lambda and this applies to me in other areas of the app where this style is super convenient.

Comment: @Jason: `std::thread` accepts a function object. A lambda *is* a function object, no conversion required. A lambda *is not* an `Orders` , and `Orders` has no handling to magically create itself from a lambda. As a result you get the error where the compiler says "I don't know how to create an `Orders*` from the unnamed lambda type"

Comment: @Jason: Note the third `thread` constructor which accepts a function object: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/thread (of which a lambda is a valid type)

Comment: Thanks, reading that makes perfect sense. so I need to return an `Orders` from the lambda.

Comment: @Jason: No, there's no reason for any lambda going on here. If you return an `Orders` from the lambda then you'll need to immediately call the lambda to get the `Orders` which it would return.

Comment: I got it now. Thanks for both explanations. I see my mistake

Answer (score 0):

What type is `Orders`? Actually, it doesn't really matter: the expression `[](){ ... }` certainly isn't of a type convertible to `Orders*`. ... and the angle brackets around the argument to `push_back()` a definitely wrong.

Did you mean to call the lambda expression?

```
vOrders.push_back(std::shared_ptr<Orders>([]() {
        TimerForProcessingOrders _timerForProcessingOrders;
        return _timerForProcessingOrders.detach();
    })()
); // ^^ note these extra parenthesis
```

... but even that shouldn't work as the lambda expression doesn't return anything (hence the also added `return`).

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I'd suggest you follow Billy ONeals train of thought. But if you want to do it your way this is a SSCE of it.

There are two changes, this lambda returns an object and is executed, thereby returning.

```
#include <vector>
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

struct Foo {
    int val;
};

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Foo> > v;
    v.push_back([]() -> std::shared_ptr<Foo> { Foo f; f.val = 5; return std::make_shared<Foo>(f); }());
    std::cout <<v[0]->val <<std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```